# Is this Scala code correct?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Why does this code crash the Scala 2.8.1 compiler?

```
val a = new Array[{ var x = 1 }](3)
```

Is it a compiler bug?

Anyway is it a legal Scala code? (I want an array of objects with anonymous class type)

*Update:*

What I want is something like:

```
class X { var x = 1}
val a = new Array[X](3)
```

but without having to define standalone X

Comment: How exactly do I type check for classes when I'm not allowed to refer to it? It doesn't even have methods that I can declare a structural type to match for.

Comment: I am at no way an expert, but since the compiler crashes I would say this is a bug.

Comment: I don't think that is legal Scala, but a compiler crash is certainly a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compiler crashes are always bugs.  But why are you trying to set `x` equal to 1 in the *type* declaration?

Your probably want one of these:

```
val a = new Array[{var x: Int}](3)
val a = Array.fill(3)(new { var x = 1 })
```

(and the compiler is happy with either of these).

Comment: Aren't there also legal compiler crashes such as a stackoverflow due to some kind of type recursion?

Comment: @gruenewa - Running out of resources during compilation is allowed, yes, at least as long as the the resource consumption is vaguely reasonable given your source code.

Comment: Thanks Rex. The latter one is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't crash for me (Scala 2.8), so it is likely a bug.